# Who am I? - Some riddle as a poem

Tags: riddle, poetry

> *Earth-born out of bloody love,
>
> unsure, though, if this is true.
>
> Above spans the old and rules
>
> the sky in first generation.
>
> Lots of children coming after,
>
> some from mother, no from other.
>
> Four sons were holding him together,
>
> fifth taking what had made he man.*

**Who am I?**

(First try writing a little poem-style riddle after reading a pretty interesting book. ^^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you thinking of

> Uranus?

> In Roman mythology, Uranus was one of the first titans, being the sky. He had many children with the earth, Gaia. The children that they bore, the Titans, the Hekatonkheires, and the Cyclopses, were all born from the earth. The fifth son that they had, the titan Cronus, castrated Uranus for sealing away the Cyclopses and Hekatonkeires in Tartarus, thus taking what had given him manhood.

Comment: Well, the book was about the Greek, but it's exactly what I thought of. Was it too easy to guess? :) Note that he himself is no titan.